# ngrx store actions with payloads causing content load to get progressively worse

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

TLDR; Dispatching actions to the store is causing significant, incremental deficiencies in the content load from http requests. Requests themselves, if not involving the store logic, or not involving taking the content of the http requests into themselves do not cause any issues regardless of if anything is done with the data after the fact(No reducer matching the specified type). Using the ngrx/entity framework as well. I can't seem to find a way to stop this deficit in performance, and the application will crash after a given period due to it.

Function used to test things out and see where the bottlenecks occur shows that the action of doing the get is the most expensive portion, as well as the waterfalls seen on the images that follow.

```
  @Effect()
  getAllClusterInfo: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType<actions.GetAllClusterInfoObjectsAction>(actions.GET_ALL_CLUSTER_INFO_OBJECTS)
  .do(_ => console.log(_))
  .switchMap(() => {
     const str = `Info: ${Math.round(Math.random() * 10000)}`;
     console.time('Full ' + str)
     console.time('Get ' + str)
     return this.service$.getAllClusterInfoObjects().do(_ => console.timeEnd('Get ' + str))
       .map(info => new actions.GetAllClusterInfoObjectsSuccessAction(info)).do(_ => console.timeEnd('Full ' + str))
       .catch(err => of(new actions.GetAllClusterInfoObjectsFailAction(err)));
   });
```

I've got a central store instance set up on my application, prior to this it was working as it should, and still does so for the most part. The problem that is coming up is that on a timed loop attaining data from the system, and firing off two actions, the amount of time that it takes for the content to get loaded, based on the waterfall view from Chrome-DevTools, is getting progressively higher, and higher to the point where the load action could actually crash the application due to the time it takes to process it.

I've done some slight testing, to verify what is currently happening, but can't seem to find a way to solve it. The issue is not in the loading of the content from the server itself, it is two calls both of which when done apart from the store/actions logic complete within <300ms.

[image: Making no calls to the actions or effects, in short no store logic]
I've created a dummy action that does not write anything to the store itself, as the time to write these contents to the store take less than a millisecond, observed with console.time and I know it's not the greatest tool in an async environment but validated with chrome performance monitor. This action can take a payload, and when given the payload of the result of the http requests, will do what's below.If I remove the payload from the dummy action that gets triggered, then the behavior stays roughly the same as making the pure html calls. 
[image: Calling the action, which dispatches the dummy action once content is available]
Making the http requests through the use of the service class, and then calling the dummy action that again does not attempt to mutate the store in any way after the payload is given to it, causes the same performance slowdown, though not as bad due to what I believe to be the problem which is the synchronicity of the actions that are being dispatched.Here are two cases the first one where the action is called, with a payload, but no reducer handles it's type(Should be basically ignored I assume.)
The second, dispatching the action with an empty payload, which again shouldn't do much of anything.[image: Calling the dummy action with a payload]
[image: Calling the dummy action with no payload]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the culprit was the use of the DevTools module, that was in place. Answer was obtained through more spot checking the tests that are generated, and this ticket, for a better explanation.
[Angular2 NGRX Performance Issues On Dispatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354606/angular2-ngrx-performance-issues-on-dispatch)